# How do I set tab size in the WPF RichTextBox

Tags: .net, wpf, tabs, richtextbox

The WPF RichTextBox can be set to accept tabs in its input. It renders the result as a 4 character indent. I'd like to change that size. How can I change the default?

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no support for this, but they are considering it for future release. Frustrating answer - I know!

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c610a492-cae8-444a-a657-05559da61fe3/ (Answer from LesterLobo - MSFT)

Answer (score 1):

Reading sams link about TabStops it seems that the answer to your question is a bit easier to solve. Just add this Style somewhere in your resources:

```
<Style TargetType="Paragraph">
  <!-- 20.0 is default. It's pixels not characters though -->
  <Setter Property="TextIndent" Value="20" /> 
</Style>
```

Unfortunately when you get the text out of the document it omits the tabs. I'm thinking of writing my own flowdocument text writer so I can get better output. Another problem is that appending text does not generate a paragraph per line or proper indents for '\t's. So I might have to create the reverse as well. Very frustrating. The FlowDocument seems like it was not really designed to be used.